# React-Native: Unable to bring Ellipsis in lengthy Text without using width

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

In React native i am trying to bring ellipsis to the lengthy text. Providing numberOfLines={1} constraint does not help, unless otherwise using max-width or width to the text component.
But i would like to achieve the ellipsis without providing a width, meaning the Text component should just take the available width and render ellipsis for the long text. Can it be achieved using flex stylings?
Please help.

```
        <TouchableOpacity style={{{ height: 82, paddingTop: 12 }}>
            <View style={{flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        left: 16,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",}}>
                <View style={{height:32, width:32}}/>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={1}>THIS IS A LONG LONG LONG DESCRIPTION, really a very long description</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Text>
                        {"Final"}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIgdu.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 82, paddingTop: 12 }}>
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      paddingLeft: 16,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    }}>
      <View style={{ height: 32, width: 32 }} />
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View>
          <Text numberOfLines={1}>THIS IS A LONG LONG LONG DESCRIPTION, really a very long description</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>
          {"Final"}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick test, your `<Text>` is actually already being cut, but you're not able to see it because of that `left` style in the wrapper `<View>`.

Change that to either `paddingLeft: 16` or `marginLeft: 16` and you should be able to see the ellipsis.

Comment: agree, the left was also causing problem